# Why is Time complexity of reverse of a sentence of words O(n)?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

I came across this article [Reverse words in a given string](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-words-in-a-given-string/)

The code is

```
void reverseWords(char *s)
{
    char *word_begin = NULL;
    char *temp = s; /* temp is for word boundry */

    /*STEP 1 of the above algorithm */
    while( *temp )
    {
        /*This condition is to make sure that the string start with
          valid character (not space) only*/
        if (( word_begin == NULL ) && (*temp != ' ') )
        {
            word_begin=temp;
        }
        if(word_begin && ((*(temp+1) == ' ') || (*(temp+1) == '\0')))
        {
            reverse(word_begin, temp);
            word_begin = NULL;
        }
        temp++;
    } /* End of while */

    /*STEP 2 of the above algorithm */
    reverse(s, temp-1);
}
```

My understanding of time complexity for this problem :

1) Iterating the entire string so `O(n)` , `n = length of the array`

2) Reverse time complexity is `O(m / 2)` `m = size of word reversing`

Why isn't the time complexity `O(n * (m / 2))` which is `O(nm) ?`

But the time complexity mentioned in the link is `O(n)` . Why are we ignoring time complexity of `reverse method?`

Comment: When you say reverse time complexity is `O(n/2)`, what's `n`? The size of the word you are reversing? Isn't that a different thing from the `n` in the `O(n)` for the whole string? So why use the same variable for two different values?

Comment: I edited the question based on your question.

Comment: So what is the relationship between `n` and `m`? They're clearly not independent. For example, a sentence with 200 letters can't have 300 letter words in it, right? Also, `reverse` isn't called for every iteration, only on some. So you can't just multiply them. (Keep fixing your mistakes and you'll eventually agree with the given answer.)

Comment: `n * m` is the number of words in the array times the average size of a word... which is just the total number of letters in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why isn't the time complexity `O(n * (m / 2))` which is `O(nm)` ?

Because you don't reverse a word per *each character*, you only do it once per `m` characters. So while scan through the word and then later reverse it gives you `O(m)` (twice `m` which is still `O(m)`), the whole process takes `n / m * O(m)` = `O(n)`, since there are only `n/m` words.

(More exactly, for word lengths `m1`, `m2`, ..., each word taking `O(m_i)` steps, and overall amount of whitespace of `s`, the algorithm requires `O(m1) + O(m2) + ... + O(s) = O(m1 + m2 + ... + s) = O(n)`, word lengths and overall amount of whitespace summing up to `n`.)